# Rtools already installed, but package prompts to new install then quits because Rtooll is already installed

Tags: r, rtools

I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible. I`m trying to install the package Giotto on Rstudio, with

```
library(devtools)
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("RubD/Giotto")
```

Then I get a prompt saying

> Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools

When clicking "yes" it starts downloading Rtools35. After the download is finished, another prompt gives

> Another version of Rtools is already installed in: C:\RBuildTools\3.5. It is recommended to uninstall the old version before installing the new version.
> Do you want to proceed anyway?

Both "Yes" and "No" fail to install. I also checked

```
> pkgbuild::rtools_path()
[1] "C:/RBuildTools/3.5/bin"
```

I tried uninstalling Rtools, but I don't have the privilege. Is this the only solution?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a common problem. The short answer is "No you will need to have privileges". Uninstall the old version and maybe reinstall the newest version afterwards if that doesnt work. Last if that still doesn't work add he path to rtools in your system environment PATH variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I`ll go through IT loops.

Comment: One way to "avoid" this in the future might be to install it in your user folder. eg: "C:/Users/[your username folder]/rtools". That's how we avoid having to get a hold of IT every time there's an update to R or R tools on local installs. But I'm not certain it will fix the PATH variable.

Comment: There is also an `install.Rtools` function that you may want to check out: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/installr/versions/0.22.0/topics/install.Rtools